# Why does this use of callable class now work?

Tags: dart

I am trying to get callable classes to work in dart, but I have ran into a few issues. First thing I realized is that a normal function

```
myFunc() {
  return 'myFunc';

}

Function.apply(myFunc,null);
```

is not working as a callable.

Then I realized that if I do

```
final myFunc = () => 'myFunc';

Function.apply(myFunc,null);
```

this works.

So now I am trying it out with classes

```
class Cars {
  call(Map<Symbol,dynamic> args) {
    return "ride";
  }
  const Cars();
}
final cars = Cars();
final jobs = {cars.hashCode :cars};

void main() {
  int code = cars.hashCode;
  print(Function.apply(jobs[code],null));
}
```

but in DartPad I get the following error

```
Uncaught exception:
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: Closure 'call$1' of Instance of 'Cars'
Arguments: []
```

are there some restrictions on the call method? Or how it works with Function.apply() that I am not finding in the docs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example works fine for me, but your program needs an entry point:

```dart
myFunc() {
  return 'myFunc';
}

void main() {
  print(Function.apply(myFunc, null));
}
```

In your class example, your `call` method requires a `Map`, but you're passing null. There is no `call` method with zero arguments, hence the `method not found: 'call'` error.

One way to fix it is by adding an empty `Map` to the parameter list in `Function.apply`:

```dart
class Cars {
  call(Map<Symbol,dynamic> args) {
    return "ride";
  }
  const Cars();
}

final cars = Cars();
final jobs = {cars.hashCode :cars};

void main() {
  int code = cars.hashCode;
  print(Function.apply(jobs[code], [Map<Symbol,dynamic>()]));
}
```

It's worth noting that you can call any method on a class with any number of arguments:

```dart
class Car {
  go(int speed, int wheels) {
    print('$speed mph, $wheels wheels');
  }
}

void main() {
  var car = Car();
  Function.apply(car.go, [50, 4]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I was reading the docs for Function.apply incorrectly.